# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, jsx

getting an error like "username undefined" don't know whats going on wrong coz i have declared username stiil getting error  plz try to solve my error

https://ibb.co/7jGyCD1

> This is my code where i got error

```
import React from 'react';
import './Message.css';
import {Card,Typography,CardContent} from '@material-ui/core';


const Message = ({message,userName}) => {

    const isUser = userName === message.userName;

    return (
        <div className={`message ${isUser && 'message_user'}`}>
            <Card className={isUser ? 'message_userCard' : 'message_guestCard'}>
                {/* if the user is logged in then show the user card  otherwise show the styiling */}
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography 
                    color='white'
                    varient='h5'
                    component='h2'>
                    <h2>{message.userName} : {message.message}</h2>
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Message;
```

> App.js
> This is my app.js file where i wrote my all logic code and i used firebase for store our data in database backend

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Input } from '@material-ui/core';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Message from './Message';
import db from './Firebase';


const App = () => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [userName,setuserName] = useState('');

  // console.log(input);
  // console.log(messages);
  // console.log(userName);

  //every single time when database change or add value in dayabase then onSnapshot run
  useEffect(()=>{
    db.collection('messages').onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>{
        doc.data()
      }))
    })
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setuserName(prompt('enter your name'))
  },[])

  //in above whenever my input value change inside useEffect code run

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setMessages([...messages, {userName: userName, text:input}])
    setInput('');
  }

  //usestate= variable in react its just a peace of code
  //useffetc = it is block of code that can executed based on a condition


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <h1>Welcome Ashish</h1>
         <h2>Welcome {userName}</h2>
        <FormControl>
          <Input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
          <Button disabled={!input} variant='contained' color='primary' type='submit' onClick={sendMessage}>send message</Button>
        </FormControl>
      </form>

      {
        messages.map(message => (
          <Message userName={userName} message={message}/>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to ensure that is you need to map over the messages array only if it is present.Consider the code below. I have added a check to render the Message component only if messages are present.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Input } from '@material-ui/core';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Message from './Message';
import db from './Firebase';


const App = () => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [userName,setuserName] = useState('');

  // console.log(input);
  // console.log(messages);
  // console.log(userName);

  //every single time when database change or add value in dayabase then onSnapshot run
  useEffect(()=>{
    db.collection('messages').onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
      setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>{
        doc.data()
      }))
    })
  },[]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setuserName(prompt('enter your name'))
  },[])

  //in above whenever my input value change inside useEffect code run

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setMessages([...messages, {userName: userName, text:input}])
    setInput('');
  }

  //usestate= variable in react its just a peace of code
  //useffetc = it is block of code that can executed based on a condition


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <h1>Welcome Ashish</h1>
         <h2>Welcome {userName}</h2>
        <FormControl>
          <Input value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
          <Button disabled={!input} variant='contained' color='primary' type='submit' onClick={sendMessage}>send message</Button>
        </FormControl>
      </form>

      { 
        messages && messages.length && messages.map(message => (
          <Message userName={userName} message={message}/>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `messages.map(message => message ? (<Message userName={userName} message={message} />) : null)` is better.

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  db.collection('messages').onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
    setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>{
      //   you miss out the `return` here
      return doc.data()
    }))
  })
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the reason

Maybe when you are creating the use state for username.
Make sure its like this "setUserName". i dont know if its correct or wrong. I always write like this. Change Your Code According to it in your App.js.